# 415 Unsupported Media Type AngularJS to SpringMVC Controller

Tags: java, angularjs, json, ajax

I'm getting this error when trying to post JSON data from angularjs controller to SpringMVC controller. I've tried a lot of solutions posted here and some other stuff available on the net as well. I already have the jackson library in my classpath. And also I'm not using maven because of internet issues.

**SpringMVC Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    String saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {

        //Will do some stuff here.
        System.out.println("INSIDE CONTROLLER");
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
app.controller('saveEmployeeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.employee = {};

    $scope.saveEmployee = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'employee',
            data: $scope.employee,
            headers:{'Accept':'application/json', 'Content': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function(data){
           console.log('something nice'); 
        });
    };
});
```

**WebConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("springmvc.com.")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/resources/static/app/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webapp/resources/static/app/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/resources/static/lib/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webapp/resources/static/lib/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/resources/static/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webapp/resources/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/resources/static/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webapp/resources/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/webapp/resources/static/views/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webapp/webapp/resources/static/views/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webapp/resources/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webapp/resources/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(
            ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true)
                .parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                .useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**WebAppInitializer**

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "springmvc.com.config";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        System.out.println("***** Initializing Application for " + servletContext.getServerInfo() + " *****");

        // Create ApplicationContext
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);

        // Add the servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("mvc-dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);

        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us '$scope.employee' data and Employee Class ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are sending header "Content" but you should send "Content-Type"
2. Do you send exactly the same fields in JSON as there are in Employee class, check if there are no additional fields, because Jackson has setting that it fail if unrecognized field is set. And there are some resolutions for this issue (like annotation on your class or change this setting)

Most important is what appear in the log file of your server application. What exception is raised as a cause of this http status. So i the solutions above not helping you, please check logs (maybe increase log level for spring) and post it here.

**UPDATE:**

I have few additional questions:

- has your Employee class got default (non args) constructor or maybe you create only constructor with arguments? Could you post your Employee class.
- Do you have any logger attached to your project, is there anything in log file, (if there is, please post it)?

Comment: Step 1 unfortunately didn't work. And yea the Employee has exact 2 fields. I was wondering since I'm entirely new to this Rest thing, do I have to put some sort of Jackson annotation in Employee class?

Comment: No, it's really not needed to place any Jackson annotation on Employee.class. By default Jackson should "JSONize" your whole object out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was actually with the jackson library. I downloaded the version "1.9.9 all" and worked pretty well.